# How to change points/line based on value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

So I want to show a line graph that turns red when the values are below 30 or above 200, and be grey for the values in between. I am having trouble getting it to change colors. It just shows the points on the graph all in grey, I am new to chart.js so any advice is helpful! I am not sure why but the update chart does not seem to update.

```js
data: {
  labels: ['7/31/2018', '11/7/2018', '2/11/2019', '4/3/2019', '5/11/2019', '7/18/2019', 'extra', 'extra'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Systolic',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'grey',
      pointRadius: '3',
      pointHoverRadius: '3',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: '1',
      data: [117, 135, 90, 100, 106, 110, 29, 300]
    }
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,

        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          suggestedMin: 50,
          stepValue: 50,
          suggestedMax: 150
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 10,
        top: 10,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      displayColors: false,
      caretSize: 5,
      bodyFontSize: 11,
      callbacks: {
        title: function() {},

        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] + 'mmHg' + ' ' + data.labels[tooltipItem.index];

        },

      },
    }
  });

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var color = 'green';
  if (datasets[0].data[i].value < 30) {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (datasets[0].data[i].value > 130) {
    color = 'red';
  } else {
    color = 'grey';
  }

  data.datasets[0].data[i].BackgroundColor = color;
  data.datasets[0].data[i].pointBackgroundColor = color;
}

myObjBar.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [this fork](https://github.com/junichi-ishikura/Chart.Bands.js) of the [Bands plugin](https://github.com/bbc/Chart.Bands.js) (because the Bands plugin only allows one band per chart, the fork allows two).

Easy to handle and much easier than writing something yourself because there's no chartjs-build-in-function for that. The plugin is exactly for your use case.

https://jsbin.com/yikayukewu/edit?html,js,output

In the JSBin you can see both solutions for the plugin and its fork. Because I'm unable or it's impossible to import the fork you can see the code but without the import it's not working. The plugin code is working if you adjust the comments.

Here is the code for the fork:

```
options: {
  bands: {
    yValueMin: 35,
    yValueMax: 55,
    belowMinThresholdColour: [
      'rgb(255, 100, 100)'
    ],
    aboveMaxThresholdColour: [
      'rgb(255, 100, 100)'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use it but it does not show up on the chart @HeadhunterKev,

Comment: I think I'm having trouble implementing it, I've tried to follow along with the documentation but I don't think its set up right